# How can I change the color of one of the options in <q-select>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I have next code:

```
        <q-select v-model="type" label="Typ"
                  :options="[
                    { label: 'Teacher', value: 'Teacher' },
                    { label: 'Student', value: 'Student' }
                    ]"
        >
          <template v-slot:append>
            <doc-tag name="Typ"/>
          </template>
        </q-select>
```

What should I write in order to make the color of the Student red. I tried a lot with nothing is working thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the slot `option`

```
  <template v-slot:option="scope">
       <q-item v-bind="scope.itemProps">
        <q-item-section>
          <q-item-label :style="scope.opt.style">{{ scope.opt.label }}</q-item-label>
        </q-item-section>
      </q-item>
    </template>
```

Check the Quasar documentation on [Select: Customizing menu options](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#customizing-menu-options)

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.7/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
 <q-select v-model="type" label="Typ"
    :options="[
      { label: 'Teacher', value: 'Teacher', style: '' },
      { label: 'Student', value: 'Student', style: 'color: red;' }
    ]"
>
  <template v-slot:option="scope">
   <q-item v-bind="scope.itemProps">
    <q-item-section>
      <q-item-label :style="scope.opt.style">{{ scope.opt.label }}</q-item-label>
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
</template>
</q-select>
</div> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.11.7/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```